# How to fetch a single value with an entity metadata wrapper?

Tags: entities

Say I want to fetch a single value from the node table: I could use the database API:

```
$value = db_query('
  SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid
', array(':nid' => $nid,))->fetchField();
```

What is the equivalent using an entity metadata wrapper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$title = $wrapper->title->value();
```

But if that's literally all you need to get from the node, an `EntityMetadataWrapper` is overkill in my opinion. Just use:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$title = $node->title;
```